# Save Radio Box Value in Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I want to save the checked values of the radio boxes but when I try to submit the button and redirect to a url based on the 3 choices it doesnt work. I debugged it, and apparently the problem is that my program is only saving the last value in the variable but not the values before. What can I do to save all the choices in 3 different variables?

HTML:

```
    <div id="schritt1">
        <p stlye="text-align:center;">frage 1</p>
        <input id="1a" type="radio" name="a" value="eins" onclick="checkedvalue('a')"/>
        <label for="1a">1</label><br/>
        <input id="1b" type="radio" name="a" value="zwei" onclick="checkedvalue('a')"/>
        <label for="1b">2</label></br>
        <input id="1c" type="radio" name="a" value="drei" onclick="checkedvalue('a')"/>
        <label for="1c">3</label>

    </div>

    <div id="schritt2" style="display:none;">
        <p stlye="text-align:center;">Frage 2</p>
        <input id="2a" type="radio" name="b" value="zweieins" onclick="checkedvalue('b')"/>
        <label for="2a">1</label><br/>
        <input id="2b" type="radio" name="b" value="zweizwei" onclick="checkedvalue('b')"/>
        <label for="2b">2</label></br>
        <input id="2c" type="radio" name="b" value="zweidrei" onclick="checkedvalue('b')"/>
        <label for="2c">3</label>
    </div>

    <div id="schritt3" style="display:none;">
        <p stlye="text-align:center;">Frage 3</p>
        <input id="2a" type="radio" name="c" value="dreieins" onclick="checkedvalue('c')"/>
        <label for="2a">1</label><br/>
        <input id="2b" type="radio" name="c" value="dreizwei" onclick="checkedvalue('c')"/>
        <label for="2b">2</label></br>
        <input id="2c" type="radio" name="c" value="dreidrei" onclick="checkedvalue('c')"/>
        <label for="2c">3</label>
    </div>

    <div id="finish-button" style="display:none;">
        <a class="btn btn-buy" onclick="checkedvalue('finish')">Ergebnis</a>

    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
 function checkedvalue(choice){
var eins;
var zwei;
var drei;

if(choice == "a") {


    eins = (jQuery('input[name=a]:checked').val());
    window.alert(eins);
document.getElementById('schritt1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('schritt2').style.display = 'block';
}


else if(choice == "b") {


    zwei = (jQuery('input[name=b]:checked').val());
    window.alert(zwei);
    window.alert(eins + zwei);
    document.getElementById('schritt2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('schritt3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('finish-button').style.display = 'block';
}



else if(choice == "c") {


    drei = (jQuery('input[name=c]:checked').val());

}

else if(choice == "finish") {
    window.alert(eins + zwei + drei);

    if(eins == "eins" && zwei == "zweieins" && drei == "dreieins" )
    {
    console.log("If 2 works");
    window.location.href = "//";
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Non of your radio buttons have value attribute, also your visible radio buttons calling `"checkedvalue('a')` with same value. Shouldn't it be something like `onclick="checkedvalue('b')` and `onclick="checkedvalue('c')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is every time this onclick() method is calling and refreshing the Javascript method.So it will be loose the previously saved values.

You can Collect all the radio Button group values At the time of form submitting using

```
 var eins;
 var zwei;
 var drei;
```

declare these variable globally(Outside of all functions) and add below code inside form submit method (write a OnSubmit method in your submit button and write the code inside )

```
$('input:radio').each(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')) {
  // You have a checked radio button here...
 var val = $(this).val();
 var name = $(this).attr('name');
if(name=="a")
{
  eins=val;
}
else if(name=="b")
 {
zwei=val;
}
else
{
drei=val;
}
 } 
else {
// Or an unchecked one here...
}
});
```

I didn't test the code,So modify as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the first hint declaring the variables globally it worked. I actually dont need the second code  because I don't need it to be submitted nor a form.

Comment: Oh.Nice.Welcome.